# Sorting empty and word array in java

Tags: java

I want to write a code which can sort char array element. But the problem is where i want to sort 'a' before 'aa' element and I don't know how to write this part. It always sort 'aa' before 'a'. At first it get inputs from user and if we write '0' it will print sorted array.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, num = 0;
        char[][] arr = new char[1000][1000];
        char[] index = new char[1000];
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            arr[i] = myObj.next().toCharArray();
            if(arr[i][0] == '0'){
                break;
            }
            else{
                num++;
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                if(arr[i][0] < arr[j][0]){
                    index = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = index;
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider that `'aa'` is not a char, instead `'a'` is a char.
If you want to sort strings the code is nearly okay.

Here an example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class First {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 0;
    String[] arr = new String[1000];
    String index = "";
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        arr[i] = myObj.nextLine();
        if(arr[i].equals("0")){
            break;
        }
        else{
            num++;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if(arr[i].compareTo(arr[j]) < 0){
                index = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = index;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print("[ ");
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
   }
}
```

Input:

```
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaa
aaaa
aaa
aa
a
0
```

Expected Output:

```
[ a aa aaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only sorting by the first char of an entered word.
Thus it seems like the input-order is preserved.

#### Issue

Adding some debug-prints shows the comparison of first-char is leading to incorrect or unwanted `aa` before `a` case:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, num = 0;
        char[][] arr = new char[1000][1000];
        char[] index = new char[1000];
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            arr[i] = myObj.next().toCharArray();
            if(arr[i][0] == '0'){
                break;
            }
            else{
                num++;
            }
            System.out.printf("Debug [%d]: '%s' \n", i, String.valueOf(arr[i]));
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                System.out.printf("Compare '%s' < '%s' = %s\n", arr[i][0], arr[j][0], (arr[i][0] < arr[j][0]));
                if(arr[i][0] < arr[j][0]){
                    index = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = index;
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a
Debug [0]: 'a' 
aa
Debug [1]: 'aa' 
Compare 'a' < 'a' = false
0
a
aa
```

#### Refactored and solved

I just added a bit output to interact with user.
Also refactored a bit (extract into methods, and control length of arrays with a configurable constant).

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class First {

    private static final int LENGTH = 10;
    private static final Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] arr = new char[LENGTH][LENGTH];
        System.out.println("Enter elements (each on a new line, 0 stops):");
        int num = readArray(0, arr);
        System.out.printf("Printing %d elements:\n", num);
        printArray(num, arr);
    }

    private static int readArray(int num, char[][] arr) {
        char[] index;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
            arr[i] = readChars();
            if (arr[i][0] == '0') {
                break;
            } else {
                num++;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (String.valueOf(arr[i]).compareTo(String.valueOf(arr[j])) < 0)  {  // entire array compared (chars in sequence) instead only: arr[i][0] < arr[j][0]
                    index = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = index;
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return num;
    }

    private static void printArray(int num, char[][] arr) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    private static char[] readChars() {
        return myObj.next().toCharArray();
    }
}
```

Output is as expected (`a` before `aa`):

```
Enter elements (each on a new line, 0 stops):
z
aa
b
a
0
Printing 4 elements:
a
aa
b
z
```

#### How it works

Entire array compared (chars in sequence) instead only the first char of each array.

before:

- `arr[i][0] < arr[j][0]`

after:

- `String.valueOf(arr[i]).compareTo(String.valueOf(arr[j])) < 0`

#### Bonus Tip: Naming can help to spot logical bugs

When renaming the methods and variable names it may get a bit clearer what the program does, we call it *semantics*:

- myObj becomes `scanner`
- i becomes `index` or wordIndex or `lineIndex` and `lastLineIndex`
- j is actually a character-index ... but in this short scope it should can be self-evident
- char-arrays can be `lines` or words
- num becomes `length` of lines or `countLines`
- and all the method-names are adjusted in *semantics* to operate on lines, expressed by name `<verb>Lines`

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class First {

    private static final int LENGTH = 10;
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] lines = new char[LENGTH][LENGTH];
        System.out.println("Enter elements (each on a new line, 0 stops):");
        int countLines = readLines(lines);
        System.out.printf("Printing %d elements:\n", countLines);
        printLines(lines, countLines);
    }

    private static int readLines(char[][] lines) {
        int linesRead = 0;

        for (int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < LENGTH; lineIndex++) {
            lines[lineIndex] = readLine();
            if (lines[lineIndex][0] == '0') {
                break;
            } else {
                linesRead++;
            }
            sortLines(lines, lineIndex);
        }

        return linesRead;
    }

    private static void sortLines(char[][] lines, int lastLineIndex) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lastLineIndex; j++) {
            if (String.valueOf(lines[lastLineIndex]).compareTo(String.valueOf(lines[j])) < 0)  {  // entire array compared (chars in sequence) instead only: arr[i][0] < arr[j][0]
                char[] line = lines[lastLineIndex];
                lines[lastLineIndex] = lines[j];
                lines[j] = line;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printLines(char[][] lines, int length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            System.out.println(lines[i]);
        }
    }

    private static char[] readLine() {
        return scanner.next().toCharArray();
    }
}
```